# Deserializing into List only picks one item

Tags: c#, xml

This is how my XML looks like:

```
<FileExtensions>
    <Text>
        <Extension>602</Extension>
        <Extension>ABW</Extension>
        <Extension>ACL</Extension>      
    </Text>
    <Script>
        <Extension>AHK</Extension>
        <Extension>APPLESCRIPT</Extension>      
    </Script>   
</FileExtensions>
```

These are the classes I'm deserializing to:

```
    [XmlRoot("FileExtensions")]
    public class FileExtensions
    {
        public FileExtensions()
        {
            Text = new List<Extensions>();
            Script = new List<Extensions>();            
        }

        [XmlElement("Text")]
        public List<Extensions> Text;

        [XmlElement("Script")]
        public List<Extensions> Script;        
    }    
    public class Extensions
    {
        [XmlElement("Extension")]
        public string name;
    }
```

This is how I'm deserializing:

```
FileExtensions extensions = new FileExtensions();
var deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FileExtensions));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
extensions = (FileExtensions)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

For some reason, my Lists have only one element each, which is the first one to appear in the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Xml you have, your current definition class doesn't quite match up due to the intemediary nodes. If you want it to work you could either change the xml to something like this:

```
<FileExtensions>
    <Text>602</Text>
    <Text>ABW</Text>
    <Text>ACL</Text>      
    <Script>AHK</Script>
    <Script>APPLESCRIPT</Script>      
 </FileExtensions>
```

And then modify your `Extension` Class to decoarate the `Name` attribute with `[XmlText]` to capture the text inside the nodes.

Or you can change your definition to something like the below

```
 [XmlRoot("FileExtensions")]
public class FileExtensions
{
    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public Text Text;

    [XmlElement("Script")]
    public Script Script;
}

public class Text
{
    [XmlElement("Extension")]
    public List<Extensions> Texts;

    public Text()
    {
        Texts = new List<Extensions>();
    }
}

public class Script
{
    [XmlElement("Extension")]
    public List<Extensions> Scripts;

    public Script()
    {
        Scripts = new List<Extensions>();
    }
}

public class Extensions
{
    [XmlElement("Extension")]
    public string name;
}
```

I ran this in a consle app and works a treat. You have a `FileExtensions` Object, with a new class representing each node `Text` and `Script`, with the list of `Extensions` inside them.

Comment: thanks. That worked. However, I had to change it to `[XmlText]` in `Extensions` class otherwise I was getting all `null` values.

Comment: You beat me to it, I'd just edited my answer to say as such =)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
[XmlArray("Text")]
[XmlArrayItem("Extension")]
public List<Extensions> Text;

[XmlArray("Script")]
[XmlArrayItem("Extension")]
public List<Extensions> Script;
```

This seems to be the common way of doing this from a bit of quick googling on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

try change XmlElement to XmlArrayItem

```
    [XmlArrayItem("Text")]
    public List<Extensions> Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your class structure reflects your xml structure quite right.  Something like this works:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileExtensions extensions = new FileExtensions();
            var deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FileExtensions));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\temp\consoleapplication3\ConsoleApplication3\XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
            extensions = (FileExtensions)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("FileExtensions")]
    public class FileExtensions
    {
        public FileExtensions()
        {
        }

        [XmlElement("Text")]
        public Text Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Script")]
        public Script Script { get; set; }
    }

    public class Text
    {
        [XmlElement("Extension")]
        public List<string> Extensions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Script
    {
        [XmlElement("Extension")]
        public List<string> Extensions { get; set; }
    }
}
```